# JavaScript dependency management without NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, dependency-management

Yes there are a few dependency or package management systems for JavaScript and other files out there. A good example can be found [here](https://github.com/wilmoore/frontend-packagers#the-contenders)! But in fact all of these systems are based on `NodeJS` or `npm`. I am not a `NodeJS` developer and I also do not have `Git` installed (I am using `Egit`). And for that feature I do not want to install `NodeJS` or `Git`.

So what options remain? I could use `Submodules` in Git, but since the `Composer` is for PHP only I do not know any other solution without installing `NodeJS` and `Git`.

Am I missing something great?

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for an offsite resource are offtopic. Voted to close.

Comment: Maybe this could be handled with a workaround, so I don't think it's offtopic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that there is a PHP version of `Bower` [here](http://bowerphp.org/)! That is of course great because NodeJS is no longer needed.

Comment: I understand that you're answering your own question, and this is likely a good fit for you. But replacing a Node.js dependency with a PHP dependency hardly seems like a win...

Comment: Well I can understand you but since I have always PHP with me this is a great alternative. It may be misleading for you, but maybe others have also more to do with PHP than NodeJS. But yes, it would be better to have a solution with no dependency!